# Display stored procedure in an anonymous block without getting too many rows error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a created stored procedure that has one in parameter and two out parameters.

I want to display the stored procedure in an anonymous PL/SQL block.

The code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE task_one
    (coun_id IN countries.country_id%TYPE,
     coun_name OUT countries.country_name%TYPE,
     reg_name OUT regions.region_name%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error! No data found!');
END;
```

Here you can see my table

[image: Countries Table]

When I try to execute the procedure in an anonymous block, I get an error which is too many rows.
In order to block the error, I thought that I can use for loop. However, It didn't work as well. Maybe the way I tried is not right at all.

Here's the anonymous block that tries to display stored procedure

```
DECLARE
    c_name countries.country_name%TYPE;
    r_name regions.region_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT country_name, region_name INTO c_name, r_name FROM Countries, Regions) LOOP
    (task_one('CA', c_name, r_name)
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c.c_name || ' ' || c.r_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of your procedure is incomplete or you did not post everything.

The procedure could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE task_one
    (coun_id IN countries.country_id%TYPE,
     coun_name OUT countries.country_name%TYPE,
     reg_name OUT regions.region_name%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    SELECT country_name, region_name
      INTO coun_name, reg_name
      FROM countries
      JOIN regions ON Countries.region_id = Regions.region_id
     WHERE country_id = coun_id;
    
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error! No data found!');
   WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error! Too many rows!');
      coun_name := NULL;
      reg_name := NULL;
END;
/
```

You have to join the two tables via the region_id.

If you also want to get the error "Too many rows", because you might get back several entries for one Country_id (error in the data?), you can do it like in the example.

You can then use the procedure in the anonymous block as follows:

```
DECLARE
    c_name countries.country_name%TYPE;
    r_name regions.region_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
   task_one('CA', c_name, r_name);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c_name || ' ' || r_name);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir!